# How to call a server side function on a jQuery click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am a newbie to ASP.NET. i wish to invoke a server side event/function on a client click, without refreshing the page. I tried ajax,__dopostback etc... but failed miserably.. may be because of my less knowledge in ASP

Can anyone help me pls

$.ajax({

```
                             type:"POST",
                               url:"projects.aspx/slides",
                               data: "{'value':''}",
                              contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
                               dataType:"json",

                              //cache:false,
                               success:function(data){
                                   alert("OK");
                                  alert(data.d);
                               },
                               error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown)
                               {
                                   alert(textStatus);
                               }

                           });
```

This is my ajax code.. Is there any problem with this??

Comment: I don't see a reason for the downvotes, this guy admits he's new! He might have tried AJAX the wrong way!

Comment: if you have tried something, place it here the code

Comment: the ajax i placed above.... projects.aspx is the same page where the script runs... the method slides is in it's cs page

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET runs server side. So it can't invoke server methods. You could use AJAX to grab data, or make a REST web service to manipulate the server which you can then call from javascript. One thing potentially worth investigating is SignalR. It's very easy to use and involves a constant dialog between the server and all clients that is completely set up for you.

I can't really help you any more than that, because you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: I have a jQuery slide in my webpage, that contains images. Obviously there is a next arrow and prev arrow, which is dynamically generating by the script. So for each click of next or prev button i have to increment the value of a hidden field and rebind the repeater in reference to the value in hidden field. So my problem is i can only have a click event of next and prev in jQuery. and the code for rebinding the repeater is in my cs page.. How can i animate the slide and rebind the repeater at the same time....

Comment: You can't. Or at the very least shouldn't. I'm sure there's some horrible, hacky approach to this using repeated requests to the server, but this is a thing that should be done entirely in Javascript. It would be both neater and easier.

Comment: But how can i rebind the repeater using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try adding those functionality in separate asp page and then if in case you need to load those html response in current asp page you can try

```
$('.btn').bind('click',function(){

        $('.div_in_which_to_load_response').load('./webservices/your_functionality_page.asp'{"data1": dummy1});
                return false;  


            });
```

Comment: How can I change the value of the hidden field in the current ASP page?
My method to cal actually contains the following two lines
HiddenField1.Value =Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(HiddenField1.Value) + 1);
bindrepeater();